# Call function who's name is stored in a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic

I have created a small classic asp file that I indend to call form asp.net using the below. I works, but it feels wrong somehow:

```
Booking.BelongsToSite = file_get_contents("http://localhost:82/test2.asp?functionName=RetBTS&param=" + User.ID);

protected string file_get_contents(string fileName)
{
    string sContents = string.Empty;
    if (fileName.ToLower().IndexOf("http:") > -1)
    { // URL 
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        byte[] response = wc.DownloadData(fileName);
        sContents = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
    }
        else
        {
            // Regular Filename 
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
            sContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }  
        return sContents;
    }
```

Can anyone see any problems with doing this?

Also is it possible to do something like the below in Classic ASP / VB script. I can't get it to call a dynamic function name:

```
dim functionName, param, result
functionName = request("functionName")
param = request("param")

result = functionName(param)
```

Also any idea how to parse the parameters. Say if I pass the parameters in the head like "1,2,3,4", how can I pass the into the parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `GetRef` instead of `Eval`.

```
dim functionName, param, result
functionName = request("functionName")
param = request("param")

result = GetRef(functionName)(param)
```

Comment: that works really well :)  - do you have any idea how to solve the parameters issue? There could be any number of parameters, how would I pass them in ?

Comment: The parameters need to be passed on the querystring of the url, e.g.  http://localhost:82/test2.asp?functionName=RetBTS&param1=" + User.ID + "&param2=" +whatever

Comment: If you know parameter count you can add manually `result = GetRef(functionName)(param1, param2, param3)`. If not, may be you should use an Array (perhaps a Dictionary object) parameter in functions called by GetRef. `GetRef(functionName)(Array("param1","param2","param3"))`. Otherwise, you have to use the Eval-Execute or pass the delimited strings etc.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for the [Eval function in VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094%28VS.85%29.aspx). You can use it to call your method in the following way (demo script is vbs in wsh):

```
Dim func, param

func = "Hello"
param = "everybody"

MsgBox(Eval(func & "(""" & param & """)"))

Function Hello(name)
Hello = "Hello " & name
End Function
```

That returns "Hello everybody", as expected.

As for your asp.net code: I'm not  going to judge whether or not your solution is sensible, I don't know the situation. It can definitely work though. Just two remarks:

1. Both WebClient and StreamReader implement IDisposable. Wrap them in a using block.
2. If you're going to download urls like that, make sure to validate your string, so that you don't go and download bad urls. Same for the function name in your classic asp that you pass in your querystring.

Menno

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Eval and evaluate aren't working for me I'm afraid. From my research, I think they have a different purpose in VBScript.

Comment: -1:  Absolute do __NOT!!__ eval something that has been posted to you via HTTP.  Yikes!  @Menno: You should check that the answer you are giving is approriate to the scenario presented in the whole of the question not just what you see in the title line.

Comment: Anthony: if you read my answer, you'll see that I point out that the function parameter needs proper validation. Probably a whitelist to check it against.

Comment: @Menno van den Heuvel - you are right that does work I must have been doing it wrong. Do you have any idea how to solve the parameters issue? There could be any number of parameters, how would I pass them in ?

Comment: A delimited list of parameters in a querystring parameter? Just split, surround with quotation marks, join them together, and stick them in there. Then proceed to be happy vbscript is not strongly typed.